# Creating one grandparent, parent, and child process using fork()

Tags: c, unix, pid

I am trying to fork processes to create exactly one grandparent, parent, and child respectively and display each pid to the standard output. How can I accomplish this? Here is my current code and output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main()
{
int pid, status, status2;
pid = fork();
switch (pid)
{
    case -1: // An error has occured during the fork process.
        printf("Fork error.");
        break;
    case 0:
        pid = fork();
        switch (pid)
        {
            case -1:
                printf("Fork error.");
                break;
            case 0:
                printf("I am the child process C and my pid is %d\n", getpid());
                break;
            default:
                wait(&status);
                printf("I am the parent process P and my pid is %d\n", getpid());
                break;
        }
    default:
        wait(&status2);
        printf("I am the Grandparent process G and my pid is %d\n", getpid());
        break;
    }
}
```

And my output:

```
I am the child process C and my pid is 8208
I am the Grandparent process G and my pid is 8208
I am the parent process P and my pid is 8207
I am the Grandparent process G and my pid is 8207
I am the Grandparent process G and my pid is 8206
```

Comment: One other note: the value returned from `fork()` should be `pid_t`, not `int`.  On many systems they are the same, but it is better not to assume that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fork()` doesn't return 1 in the parent, it returns the pid of the child.

You probably want to change your `case 1`s to `default`.

Also, in your outer `switch`, the `case 0` falls through into `case 1`.  You probably want a `break;` following the inner `switch`, between lines 28 and 29.

Comment: Got it. After making the appropriate changes I am still getting some logic flow error. Here is my new output: 
I am the child process C and my pid is 8208
I am the Grandparent process G and my pid is 8208
I am the parent process P and my pid is 8207
I am the Grandparent process G and my pid is 8207
I am the Grandparent process G and my pid is 8206

Also I tried the break; statement following the inner switch but I get the same output.

Comment: My apologies. It works the way it is supposed to. Thank you very much!